# Jaspersoft Derived Table error when running SELECT query

Tags: sql, postgresql, derived-table

I'm currently running a `SELECT` query in the derived tables part of creating a domain in Japsersoft's AWS BI Suite. However when I do, I get the following error:

> **com.jaspersoft.commons.semantic.metaapi.MetaDataException:** Cannot execute JDBC Query.
>
> **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:** ERROR: transaction is read-only

Does anyone know why this could be and if so point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

According to a [Jaspersoft forum post](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/525264/psqlexception-error-transaction-read-only), this can be solved by installing the latest PostgreSQL JDBC driver.