# Jasper report runs in preview, but not jasper server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I have a report that is running a pretty big query, it returns a lot of data and also has a parameter that is going to used as an input control fro the report server.  However the issue is that when I upload it to the server, it errors.  This is the error log it gives

```
Error Message
Error filling report (Error UID: 9f1a27b4-5bb1-40df-ab67-23ff44f15d66)
Error Trace
com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: Error filling report Arguments: at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$FillResultListener.reportFillError(EngineServiceImpl.java:1336) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.notifyError(BaseFillHandle.java:216) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:138) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$SynchronousExecutor.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:961) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.startFill(BaseFillHandle.java:169) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$AsynchronousReportFiller.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:912) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1840) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runWithDataSource(EngineServiceImpl.java:1159) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1088) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:983) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for: Financial_summary_report_test. at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:347) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.java:166) at com.jaspersoft.commons.util.JSControlledJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JSControlledJdbcQueryExecuter.java:111) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1245) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:723) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.setParameters(BaseReportFiller.java:429) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:570) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:123) ... 10 more Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: transaction is read-only Detail: at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157) at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886) at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255) at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555) at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417) at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302) at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96) at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:310) ... 17 more
```

The errors don't mean much to me, and I don't find them all that helpful, I can tell that there are errors for:   Error filling report Arguments, Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for, ERROR: transaction is read-only Detail: at.  Does anybody actually know what it means?

Again it will work in studio, but not jasper report server.  I did a smaller test report and it ran on the server just fine...

Comment: I can guess that something wrong with input control value or whole SQL query. Can you turn on logging in JasperServer for JSControlledJdbcQueryExecuter and JRJdbcQueryExecuter? Also, you can attach the JRXML  to the question, to have more reasonable feedback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jaspersoft Derived Table error when running SELECT query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403670/jaspersoft-derived-table-error-when-running-select-query)